# Java RMI app works fine from XP, but refuses connection from Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, rmi

We are currently evaluating upgrading from XP to Windows 7, but have one last sticking point, we can't seem to run our Java RMI application from Windows 7.

I'm using the same JRE / Classpath from both machines, is there any other gotcha's that I'm missing?

**Update**

I have run Wireshark on both machines, and it appears the Windows 7 box makes the request, but the response coming back from the server fails with

```
Trans2 Response, QUERY_PATH_INFO, Error: STATUS_OBJECT_PATH_NOT_FOUND
```

any ideas where I go from here?

**Update 2**

I have created a fresh XP installation (gotta love virtual machines) and the application runs without a problem, clearly something has changed in Windows 7

**Update 3**

We've created a fresh Windows 7 install, in the same datacenter as the server and that connects fine, so my friendly(!) network admin needs to sort out his network, definitely looking like a firewall issue somewhere. Thanks to all (especially Lucian) for all the time you've spent on this.

Comment: Likely to be a Firewall issue.

Comment: thanks, but still no joy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps anyone in future, there was a "Policy Map Inspection" on our Cisco router, we disabled "inspect skinny" and everything works. [Cisco Tech note](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_tech_note09186a008085283d.shtml) this was stopping all returning RMI traffic before it made it to the firewall, so was very hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Did you unblock the port you use for your application's RMI?

I remember having this problem once.

The default port for RMI is 1099 if I remember correctly, but you can set that in the command line.

Edit:
Are sections A.3 or C.4 from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/faq.html) or section 6.0 from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/codebase.html) of any help?

Edit2:
[Here](http://community.wdc.com/t5/WD-TV-Live-Networking/Windows-7-media-shares/td-p/10734)'s a link to an access permissions thread related to the response found with Wireshark.

Comment: The server must have the port open as it works fine from the XP box, I have turned off the firewall on the Win 7 box

Comment: Can you catch any exception thrown by the client and put them here (or at least the exception type)?

Comment: java.io.InterruptedIOException java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Comment: it's weird, it pulls over the login screen via RMI, then fails when you try and login, tries 20 times (only shows the errors above after the first attempt) then I get a dialog box saying there was an error during JRMP connection establishment

Comment: Might it have anything to do with file/share access?

Comment: Thanks for helping, file/share access from the client? (win7 in this example)

Comment: Might be both. Please have a look at the link posted in edit #2 and tell me if it helps.

Comment: I have to go for about 3 hrs. If you want I can join chat when I get back, and try and help you with this. Leave a comment if so, and I'll leave another comment with the chat room I'll create when I get back.

Comment: thanks for the offer, I'm out of the office for the night in an hour, maybe tomorrow, thanks again for the help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9144/discussion-between-nick-and-lucian-pantelimon)